# Ionic - App works on ripple but not on real device

Tags: php, android, authentication, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app and there is a login at the start. On ripple everything works fine, but when i try it on my android device, nothing happens when I click on "login". Here is the function which is called when someone click the button:

```
$scope.doLogin = function () {

    if(!angular.isDefined($scope.loginData.username) || !angular.isDefined($scope.loginData.password) || $scope.loginData.username.trim() == "" || $scope.loginData.password.trim() == ""){
        alert("Bitte geben Sie Benutzername und Passwort ein!");
        return;
    } else{
        // Username und Passwort überprüfen

        $http.get('http://example.com/checkUserData.php?username=' + $scope.loginData.username.trim() + '&passwort=' + $scope.loginData.password.trim()).then(function (response) {

            if (response.data == "login_done") {
                Auth.setUser({
                    username: $scope.loginData.username
                });

                $state.go("app.startseite");
            }
            else if (response.data == "error01") {
                // Username und Passwort wurden nicht korrekt übermittelt
                $scope.showAlert("Login Fehlgeschlagen!", "Etwas lief schief, versuche es später nochmal!");
                return;
            }
            else if (response.data == "error02") {
                // Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank
                $scope.showAlert("Login Fehlgeschlagen!", "Die Verbindung zur Datenbank ist gescheitert, versuche es später nochmal!");
                return;
            }
            else if (response.data == "error03") {
                // Benutzername wurde nicht gefunden
                $scope.showAlert("Login Fehlgeschlagen!", "Der Benutzername wurde nicht gefunden!");
                return;
            }
            else if (response.data == "error04") {
                // Das Passwort ist falsch
                $scope.showAlert("Login Fehlgeschlagen!", "Das Passwort ist falsch!");
                return;
            }

        })
    }

};
```

It sends the userdata to a php file and the php file checks the data on a database. Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

Comment: its nice to know im not the only one struggling with this, did you ever find a solution?